# Swing: passing data from JFrame to another

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 2 forms in my program, one is basic application form which shows when app starts and second is form for adding entities to database. It works intuitively: in default form you click `add` button, second form shows, where you fill some text areas and click `done` button.

My question, how to pass data from second form to first one?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  'Form 2' should be a modal `JDialog`.  This comes up around every 8 hours on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
method 1 :
1 : create 1 form
2 : add all fields for entering fields and also the fields from the confirmation form
3 : hide the confirmation fields
4 : when user clicks submit , hide the fields of first form , show the fields of second form

thus you all the data in one form only and you can handle the data as you want

ohk then lets try this

create a form 1
create a form 2
create a bean class having all the fields from form 1
now create a simple main class calling form 1
when user submits the form 1 , take all the values from form1 , create an object of the bean , store the values in the bean object , thus you are still in the main class 
after setting the values in the bean , call the form 2 frame , and set the fields in form 2 by using the same object of the bean class
```

Comment: yes, this is very good method, but it isn't possible cause of app complexness

Comment: its ohk if downvoted , just an explanation keep you barred from repeating the same mistake ,anyways , glad i could help

Comment: *"care to explain"*  See my comment on the question.  That's the reason.  Yours is an overblown (poorly formatted) solution to a simple problem that is discussed every day..

Comment: so its not wrong , but poorly formatted . ohk now i can die in peace :) :) :)